Expo router - Navigating to dynamic route from URL leads to a render bug on web
HELP!
Hi it is the first post I ever write so please be indulgents and let me know if my post miss some informations :)
I encountered a problem with expo router on web. My application uses a Tabs navigation. The problem is that if I try to navigate to a nested dynamic page of my app from an URL, I lend on the requested page but the <Slot /> component is not render correctly. My TabBar is sticked to the top border of my window. I think I need to precise that all the useEffects standing on the requested page are triggered and that if I inspect the DOM I find all the tags I expected but the page is not displayed in my browser.
I create a minimum to produce example with a file structure looking like this:
app
   _layout.tsx
   index.tsx
   challenges
      _layout.tsx
      [challengeId.tsx]
      index.tsx

app/_layout.tsx:
import { Tabs } from "expo-router";

export default function AppLayout() {
    return (
        <Tabs
            initialRouteName="index"
        >
            <Tabs.Screen
                name="index"
            />
            <Tabs.Screen
                name="challenges"
            />
        </Tabs>
    );
}

app/index.tsx:
import { Text, View } from "react-native";
import { ReactNode } from "react";

export default function (): ReactNode {
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>Index</Text>
        </View>
    );
};

app/challenges/_layout.tsx:
import { View, Text } from "react-native";
import { Slot } from "expo-router";

export default function ChallengesLayout() {
    return (
        <View
            style={{ flex: 1 }}
        >
            <Text>Challenges Layout</Text>
            <Slot />
        </View>
    );
}

app/challenges/index.tsx:
import { Link } from 'expo-router';
import { View, Text } from "react-native";

export default function () {
    return (
        <View
            style={{
                flex: 1,
            }}
        >
            <Text>Hello from index without layout</Text>
            <Link href="/challenges/abdef">View challenge</Link>
        </View>
    );
}


app/challenges/[challengeId].tsx:
import { View, Text } from "react-native";
import { useLocalSearchParams, useGlobalSearchParams, usePathname, useSegments, useRouter } from "expo-router";
import { useEffect } from "react";

export default function () {
    const { challengeId } = useLocalSearchParams<{ readonly challengeId: string; }>();

    return (
        <View
            style={{
                flex: 1,
                backgroundColor: "green",
                height: 100,
                width: 100,
            }}
        >
            <Text>challenge id {challengeId}</Text>
        </View>

    );
}

If I am navigating to [challengeId].tsx from a  it works perfectly but if I am navigating from an url in a web browser the behavior I described before happens. If I navigate to this page with an external link pointing to my application inside an Ios or an Android it works perfectly.
Page when navigating from URL:
Bug when navigating from URL

Page when navigating from link:
Expected behavior

I have tried many different file structure and I read the documentation but I have not succeed to understand how to reach the behavior I expect...
